# Bittorrent Sync encryption

Tags: encryption, audit, p2p, bittorrent

[Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync), a new product from BitTorrent, Inc., has been [cited](http://www.wired.com/business/2014/02/bittorrent-sync/) as a viable alternative to other cloud-storage platforms. The Sync [FAQ](http://www.bittorrent.com/help/faq/sync) indicates that an encryption scheme is being used, but does not comment on specifics.

Does there exist any information about the type of encryption that BitTorrent Sync is using, and whether or not the implementation is secure?

Answer (score 3):

The information you asked for is given [here](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync/technology) on their official site. I am copy/pasting a small relevant excerpt below.

> BitTorrent Sync was designed with privacy and security in mind. The
>   system uses SRP for mutual authentication and for generating session
>   keys that ensure Perfect Forward Secrecy. All traffic between devices
>   is encrypted with AES-128 in counter mode, using a unique session key.
>   Modification requests are all verified using Ed25519 signatures and
>   only systems with full access keys can generate valid modification
>   requests.

Comment: Now, the piece of information is deleted in the official website. It would be nice to understand how the system is doing now in BTsync 2.3.

Answer (score 3):

The information provided from Bittorrent is pretty lame. Since it is not open source i don't use it. But the Free Software Foundation is [working on it](http://libreplanet.org/wiki/Group%3aSyncReplacement)

Comment: tbh its unattractive (for me atleast) because it takes so much CPU that you can't do anything else, not because of its license :)

Comment: i don't know if they were using the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set or do you have an old CPU running?

Comment: Neither, I think its because of their design as they use your machine's resources to store and secure other users' data as well. So if you become part of their P2P overlay, you sort of volunteer your resources as well.

Comment: Great to see that there's interest in an open source alternative

Comment: @xkcd the Sync product does this? my understanding from reading about it is that it only transfers data between the machines you specify.

Answer (score 3):

**Update as of Nov. 19, 2014**

A security analysis of BTSync from a group at Hackito 2014 has been released, with generally unfavorable results. An official response from BitTorrent seems to address many of the issues raised.

[BitTorrentsync security & privacy analysis – Hackito Session results](http://2014.hackitoergosum.org/bittorrentsync-security-privacy-analysis-hackito-session-results/)*

*[Discussion on HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8618067)

[BitTorrent official response to Hackito release](http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/32592-bittorrent-sync-security-is-our-highest-priority/)*

*[Discusion on HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8626501)

Many HN commenters have identified [Pulse](https://ind.ie/pulse/)/[Syncthing](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing) as open source alternatives.